# Does the default Windows installation folder differ on non-English locales?

Tags: windows, installation

By default, Windows is installed to `C:\Windows` for English editions (the drive letter can differ).

Does this differ for non-English editions, or for those that use different character sets?

Note: I found out that the name of the `Program Files` folders *does* [change by locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Files), but haven't found anything about the Windows directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware. On all european languages I can confirm you windows folder is still C:\Windows, and I suspect this will be the same for different charsets, although I can't confirm the last fact.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows Directory can be identified by `CSIDL_WINDOWS` and by  `%SystemRoot%` on all systems, so if you need to find that folder, use that indirection... that should also identify the folder if someone has moved Windows.